# WIX API-Query-filter for date-created suddenly returns 500 Response

Tags: python, json, django, velo

Context: WIX-API https://dev.wix.com/docs/rest/articles/getting-started/api-query-language

I am using the following query, to get all orders that are beyond the defined date.

(Using Python in context of Django-Framework)

I used this query a lot of times and suddenly it failed.

```
        data = {
            "query": {
                "filter": "{\"dateCreated\": {\"$gte\": \"" + start_date + "\"}",
                "paging": {
                    "limit": 100,
                    "offset": counter,
                },
                "sort": "[{\"dateCreated\": \"desc\"}]"
            }
        }
```

When i delete the filter-options, the query works, so apparently, the mistake must be within the filter-option.

I couldn't find any recent release notes from WIX-Documentation that may have had an effect on my query.

I also tried a depressing amount of different variations for the query, but nothing helped.

Additional context:

```
start_date = "2023-01-01T00:00:01.222Z"
url = 'https://www.wixapis.com/stores/v2/orders/query'

headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
'Authorization': api_key,
'wix-site-id': site_id
}
```

Of course: i checked site-id and the api-key if there are any mistakes

Posting the request:

`response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)`

The answer is always <Response [500]>.